# How should I declare auto increment variable in the virtual table of stored procedure

Tags: sql, auto-increment

I have a stored procedure like this

```
create procedure onedata

as

begin

declare @input_data table (Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(500) . .... )

insert into @input_data .....
....

end
```

But i am not able to declare Id to be **AUTO_INCREMENT**.It showing some error.
Please suggest some solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please Read all the comments carefully written over here...i thin it will be helpfull to you http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/8f67388b-5e34-46fc-b3db-686da32431d8

Answer (score 28):

This depends on the variety of SQL you are using.

For SQL Server

```
 declare @input_data table (Id int NOT NULL identity(1,1), name varchar(50))
```

Answer (score 8):

From your syntax, I'm guessing you are using SQL Server.  If so, use `identity` instead of `auto_increment`:

```
declare @input_data table (Id int primary key identity, ... )
```